# Issue moving razor components with type constraints to a separate class library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

When moving shared Razor components with constrained type parameters to a separate Razor Class Library, errors are shown and syntax highlighting does not work. These components were working fine before.

Target framework .NET 7.0, using Visual Studio 2022 updated to the latest version.

[image: Syntax highlighting issue]

The highlighted error is this:
*Unexpected literal following the 'typeparam' directive. Expected 'line break'*

**TestComponent.razor** :

```
@using DDP.Core.Lib.Models;
@using DDP.Core.Lib.Services;
@typeparam T where T : BaseModel;
@typeparam TA where TA : BaseAuditModel;

<InputText @bind-Value="TestInput" />
```

**TestComponent.razor.cs** :

```
using DDP.Core.Lib.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace DDP.Core.Razor
{
    public partial class TestComponent<T,TA> : ComponentBase
        where T : BaseModel
        where TA : BaseAuditModel
    {

        protected string TestInput { get; set; } = "";

    }
}
```

The odd thing is occasionally the error disappears, and syntax highlighting works again. But at a certain point the error will appear again.

This github issue seems to be referring to a similar issue, which should have been fixed in .NET 6.0: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/32193#issuecomment-828920733

Comment: `The odd thing is occasionally the error disappears` Do you mean the error show occasionally? Have you tried to clean your project and rebuild.

Comment: @XinranShen I tried many times to clean, rebuild, restart visual studio, restart computer, ... The error can disappear, and syntax highlighting works again when I change something in the file, but only temporarily.

Comment: So strange, I don't know if the visual studio or .net cause this, Maybe you can post this issue in Asp.net Core github.

Comment: I've seen this often it likely due to the namespace changes. Partial classes don't refactor well when the files are moved. The razor files namespace will be the folder structure unless specified. Make sure you match this in the code behind file.

Comment: @BrianParker I've seen the same issues when moving files. So to avoid this, for this test I created a TestComponent from scratch inside the Razor Class Library.